# 500 error when I publish the weatherforecast API in Azure, how do I debug this?

Tags: azure, api, deployment, azure-web-app-service

500 error code when calling published API to Azure:

Steps to create Api project (works locally):

- open Visual Studio 2022
- choose API project on windows
- weather forecast api project automatically generated, has Swagger integrated
- tested locally, works OK: https://localhost:7264/swagger/index.html // has a single get request, avalable at: https://localhost:7264/WeatherForecast

Steps to deploy to Azure:

- from VS, right click on project, Publish
- target = Azure
- Azure service used to host app: "Azure App Service (Windows)"
- choose subscription
- create new (App Service): give it a name (wfappservice), choose existing resource group, create hosting plan with Size S1.
- In the "Api Management" section - create new instance: WFA1api; API URL suffix: wf
- Go to Azure portal - RG selected earlier - find here the API Management created earlie i.e. WFA1api
- Inside the API Management service, choose APIs - choose the WFA1api instance - right click it - choose Import API - browse to the OpenAPI specification (json file downloaded earlier from the Swagger page from the local project) - click Import
- To test, go to the TEST tab (from the same API Management service instance) - click on the GET request (shows up here from the OpenAPI specification file imported on the previous step) - click on SEND on the request -> I get error 500:

> {
> "statusCode": 500,
> "message": "Internal server error",
> "activityId": "f773cfca-45a4-4a2f-b1ed-96d1ef2ef66f"
> }

On the TRACE tab, I see:

> Trace is not available because response does not contain Ocp-Apim-Trace-Location header.

Any idea on how I can solve or debug this error? And how do I make the Api call if I skip the Api Management step, what is the procedure in that case?
What if my project also has a database?

Thank you

Comment: Try this. Should work similar for the API project too. : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have deploy an App service with API management follow the below steps
- Open visual Studio and create a sample `ASP.NET Core API`
  and run it locally as below.

[image]

- Now deploy it to azure portal **Right Click on Project** ->Click on **Publish**

[image]

- Select the Windows as below

[image]

- Click on Create and fill the required details as below and click on next.

[image]

- Click on Create to API management as below.

[image]

- Fill the **required details** as below and click on **Create**

[image]

- Select the API and web application and click on finish and then click on close

[image]

- After that click on **Publish**

[image]

Note: In some cases, the APi is not deploying into App service in that case follow below steps.

- After Deployment GOTO Resource group open **App service** and **Api management**. Select your API management as below and click on link.

[image]

- Follow the steps as below.

[image]

- After that GOTO App service and -> GOTO Api management as shown below.

[image]